# Can we use sleep arrows instead of tranq bombs to capture a monster?

Tags: monster-hunter-3-ultimate, monster-hunter-4-ultimate

When it’s capturing time, and the monster is trapped, do sleep arrows have different effects from Tranq bombs?

That is, in this situation, could we kill the monster by accident if we used Sleep arrows, or are they interchangeable with Tranq bombs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You cannot capture a monster by inflicting it with the Sleep effect. Inflicting Sleep is not the same as Tranquilizing a monster, as they are two different things.

You have to use Tranq bombs or Tranq shots to capture a monster, assuming it's weakened appropriately.

See posts like the ones in [threads like this](https://www.reddit.com/r/MonsterHunter/comments/4qdou0/sleeping_monsterscapturing/):

> Your logic is sound, but the only reason it doesn't work out is that sleep and tranq are two different statuses. Tranqing won't sleep a monster, and sleeping won't capture a monster.
>
> Capping is pretty straightforward once you know the mechanics. A monster must meet all three of the following criteria to be captured:
>
> - Be below their capturable HP threshold. This is dependant on the monster, but it's usually around 10%~30% of their max HP
> - Be in a trap
> - Have a Tranquiliser status of 100. I believe Tranq bombs and Tranq bullets apply 50 Tranq status each, and are also affected by the "Status Attack Up/Down" skills (But the only way this really manifests is that if you have SA down, you'll need three tranq bombs/shots to cap).